# Melhor forma de filtrar (validar) dados resgatados de uma $_SESSION

Tags: php, session

Estou criando um cadastro e possuo uma sessão `$_SESSION['usuario']['cpf']`;

Eu estou validando os dados que recebo por POST e GET com a função `filter_input` do PHP. Porém, a documentação diz: [INPUT_SESSION (não implementado ainda)](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php). Neste caso. como devo validar de forma segura meus dados resgatados de uma session para um cadastro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um das formas pode usar pra validar é fazer uso da função *[filter_var](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-var.php)*.

Basta atribuir o valor da sessão a uma variável e passar a mesma pra função ou passar a sessão que quer validar diretamente para a função.

Mais detalhes aqui http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-var.php